# Python 2.5 version of array.array.tostring()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, arrays, gdata

I am using 2.5 on GAE using some of the Crypto modules from gdata python modules. I am able to use hashAndSign on a string, but the function returns an array.array of 'B' unsigned characters.

I'm still experimenting on getting it all together, but one thing I'm stumbling on now is getting an:

```
array('B', [120, 231, 49, 2, 125, 143, 213, 14, 214, 66, 52, 11, 124, 154, 99, 179])
```

to be a string representation like:

```
'x\xe71\x02}\x8f\xd5\x0e\xd6B4\x0b|\x9ac\xb3'
```

How can I get the array to be a string like that?

I know this is a simple thing, but it is stumping me.

I need this so I can do a .encode('base64') to send to my client app which hopefully will be able to use it to verify the string I signed.

Comment: Please format your code appropriately, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title "Python 2.5 version of array.array.tostring()?" is puzzling. The `tostring()` method of `array.array` objects has been available for a very long time:

```
Python 1.5.2 (#0, Apr 13 1999, 10:51:12) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Copyright 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam
>>> import array
>>> q = array.array('B', [120, 231, 49, 2, 125, 143, 213, 14, 214, 66, 52, 11, 124, 154, 99, 179])
>>> q.tostring()
'x\3471\002}\217\325\016\326B4\013|\232c\263'
>>>
```

Aside: Yes, that's right, once upon a time, `repr()` did octal, not hex.

What did you actually try in Python 2.5? What was the outcome? Copy/paste the full stack trace and error message into an edit of your question.

Comment: Man what difference between our answers? So why did you answer as I did?

Comment: @scr: Man is your diff program broken? Two things: (1) you answered as though the OP had not mentioned tostring() (2) I attempted to get him to supply code and stacktrace so that we could help him with his problem.  So why did you answer as a subset of @DSM's answer.

Comment: I guess decision which i've proposed more rational than @DSM's. Okay so what is better in your answer than in my one? Anyway ok, let it be, I don't mind.

Comment: Must have been a loose nut behind the keyboard last night! I don't know how I managed to not be able to just use .tostring(), but of course it is working just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the .tostring() method isn't available -- which makes me think that this array is different from the usual array.array, because .tostring() was around at least as far back as [python 2.4](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/module-array.html) -- then

```
>>> import array
>>> q = array.array('B', [120, 231, 49, 2, 125, 143, 213, 14, 214, 66, 52, 11, 124, 154, 99, 179])
>>> ''.join(chr(c) for c in q)
'x\xe71\x02}\x8f\xd5\x0e\xd6B4\x0b|\x9ac\xb3'
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Or just `array.tostring` method:

```
>>> a = array.array('B', [120, 231, 49, 2, 125, 143, 213, 14, 214, 66, 52, 11, 1
24, 154, 99, 179])
>>> a.tostring()
'x\xe71\x02}\x8f\xd5\x0e\xd6B4\x0b|\x9ac\xb3'
```